# PHP mail to variable

Tags: forms, phpmailer, php

I've searched and searched for something similar, but i think i'm not doing it right. So i will ask a question. This is very basic. My problem is as follows:

I have a multi-page form, consisting of 4 pages + 1 preview page. On the preview page, upon submitting i want the entire form data to be sent to 2 different mail adresses. One standard, and the other one, the one that the user has submitted.

So i have:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];

  $visitor_email = $_POST['email'];

  $message = $_POST['message'];

?>

<?php

 $email_from = 'mail@company.com';

 $email_subject = "New Form submission";

    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
                            "Here is the message:\n $message".



$to = "yourname@yourwebsite.com, $email /n";

 $headers = "From: Company";


  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);

?>
```

How should I insert the submitted $email variable in order for it to work?

Comment: Indent code blocks 4 spaces (highlight and Ctl-k) for syntax highlighting and good presentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the `mail()` function documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) the `$to` parameter will take a comma-separated list of addresses as you have attempted, but should have no line break at the end.
Also, your variable is `$visitor_email`, rather than `$email`.

```
$to = "yourname@yourwebsite.com, $visitor_email";
```

You might also consider adding the visitor's email as a CC or BCC rather than the TO address. In that case, add it as a CC or BCC header (separated by `\r\n`), but you need to be cautious to be sure that the address is an email address and contains no line break characters which could be used for [header injection](http://www.securephpwiki.com/index.php/Email_Injection).

```
// The From should be an email address
$headers = "From: company@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: $visitor_email;
```

Comment: Yes, I was in a hurry to write some sample code. Perfect answer. Just what i needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `\n`

```
$to = 'yourname@yourwebsite.com,' . $visitor_email;
```

Comment: This is php not js, remove the `+` sign, instead put `.` sign

Comment: '+' is not the string concatenation operator in PHP.  The period ('.') is.